# angular2 ,use <router-outlet> in component which is dynamic created

Tags: angular

if the component which is dynamic created has router config , how can i get it work

the project:
https://github.com/CK110/angular2-stackoverflow.git

Comment: Please add the exact error messages to your question. Also there is not enough information about where and when the component is created, how the created component and it's parent looks like and also not how the routes look like. Please provide a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, l am Not familiar with Plunk。 And i shared the code in github ,https://github.com/CK110/angular2-stackoverflow/tree/master 。 and thank you very much

Comment: Please add the code as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: in the project ,  'angular2-stackoverflow-master/showcase/app/module/component-one/component-one.component.ts' ，how to do use the <router-outlet>?